# Play a defined song on Spotify with Google Actions

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I am a new user to Google Home SDK. I am developing a simple app where it takes what I said and takes some defined actions.

What I wanted to implement is, when I say "play the special song for someones-name", Google assistant will respond "here you go" followed by playing the defined song from Spotify. I can hard code the artist's name, album into the app. And I have already linked Spotify to my Google Home Assistant.

I have a couple specific questions after getting lost in reading the topics on [Create conversational experiences from scratch](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational) by Google:

(1) Suppose I just need to hard code the song and album name and let Spotify play it, is there any code snippet for that purpose? I'm new to Node.js, so may be it's easier than I thought.

(2) I am developing the app using my dev account on GCP, say Account-A, it is different from the Google Account I signed in on my home device, say Account-B. How do I deploy and test the app on the home device?

Much appreciated for your help and advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to start up a standard Spotify session through a conversational action. If you have the media file, you could have your conversational action play a [MediaResponse](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/rich-responses#media_responses).

Alternatively, you may instead want to create a [routine](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/7029585?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) that accepts a given query and completes an action. That will allow you to start a media stream for whatever you want.